# I'm making an SQLite database but I have many similar tables - is there a way to combine them?

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I'm trying to store price and volume information of products on an in-game "stock market", and the data available is the current buy price, sell price, amount of items sold in the last 7 days, and amount of items bought in the last 7 days.

Right now, I have a table for the buy prices from the last 24 hours, with the columns (time, item1, item2, item3, ...) and in each row, there's a timestamp, and then a price of each item at that time.

I then have a nearly identical table for sell price, buy volume, and sell volume (meaning, the column names are the same, but the data stored is different).

To recreate the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE buy_prices (
time INTEGER NOT NULL,
item1 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
item2 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
...
itemN INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

repeat for table sell_prices, buy_volume, and sell_volume

On a set interval, the table buy_prices is updated with

```
INSERT INTO buy_prices(time, item1, item2, ... itemN) 
VALUES (api_response['lastUpdated'], api_response['item1']['buy'], api_response['item2']['buy'], ... api_response['itemN']['buy']);
```

and then similar for sell_prices, buy_volume, sell_volume (with different keys for the api responses)

This is my first time making a database so I feel like I'm missing something glaringly obvious, but is there a way to combine all of these into one table? In my head I was thinking of something like a dictionary where each cell would store all 4 values, but I don't know if this is possible, nor if this is something reasonable.

tl;dr should I have many similar tables, or is there a solution with many values in each cell?

Comment: Please read the tag info wiki for the tag you used ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info ) and provide a MRE as described there.

Comment: @Yunnosch added, hope that's enough

Comment: This data model looks weird. With one column per product you must know how many products there are (or define the maximum number of possible products in your database). In a typical data model you would rather have one product table with a row per product. This table can contain the current buying price and selling price or you can have separate tables (e.g a product_supplier table linking to the product's supplier and maybe even with a date range for which that price is valid).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the problem with a product table w/ one row per product is that I want to know past prices as well, so as to have a 24 hour prices graph. Earlier on I was thinking of doing 6 columns `time | product name | buy price | sell price | buy volume | sell volume` but that would end up having a ridiculous amount of rows (amount of products * (24 hours / time between measurements)). Is a ridiculous amount of rows a worthy trade-off?

Answer (score 0):

you can use UNION or UNION ALL statement to merge those tables.
The UNION operator removes eliminate duplicate rows, whereas the UNION ALL operator does not.

```
with merged_table as(

select field1, field2, field3...., fieldn
from tablename1

union 

select field1, field2, field3...., fieldn
from tablename2 )

select * from merged_table;
```

you should select the  fields in the same order from table1 and table2...

Comment: If I understand unions correctly, would this not just cram them all together into one table without any info on what table they came from? I was looking for a way to combine rows from different tables into one row if that makes sense

Comment: If you create those tables with the same fields, and same data types you could use the query above and that should work, anyway you can replace field names the shared query